# A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am getting a error, when calling a spring-cxf-webservice from spring batch application.This error is happening only when its calling from batch.When calling from the normal soap UI its working fine.And once its calling from batch some of the records getting processed.Error is happening for a few records.Checked the SOAP version of batch and webservice and its same.

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint.
                at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:144)
                at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1627)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1494)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1402)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:649)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
                at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
```

Batch Configuration

```
<jaxws:client id="mainClient"
              serviceClass="com.batch.service.MainSoap"
              address="${url}" />
```

Any help or way to identify the root cause would be appreciated

Comment: can you share the specific parts of your configuration?

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu edited question with Batch Configuration.

Comment: You haven't shown us the configuration/code that hooks your mainClient Jax WS client object into Spring Batch.

Comment: which all configurations are needed?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the Soap-Binding.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="mainClient" serviceClass="com.batch.service.MainSoap"
  address="${url}">

  <jaxws:binding>
    <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
  </jaxws:binding>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Specifying binding didn't help in my case.

Comment: How to make binding soap 1.2 without spring? Spring does it according to `<soap version="1.2">` somehow and i need to do the same without spring (cxf only)

Answer (score 1):

add  this annotation on your service interface, I tried  its working for me

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

The class DeliveryService is generated:

```
 @WebService(targetNamespace = "http://...", name = "ServiceInterface")
 @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

 public interface ServiceInterface {
 @WebResult(name = "response", targetNamespace = "http:///", partName = "response")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encounter the same problem using the CXF framework. It was due to a bad configuration of the endpoint: the wsdlLocation wasn't pointing at the wsdl-file...
There is various way to define the wsdl location: it can be provide during the endpoint initialisation (the endpoint constructor take an optional  wsdlLocation as parameter) or by giving the wsdl2java task an "wsdlLocation" argument (if you generate your classes from the wsdls).

Pointing at a wrong wsdlLocation maybe the cause of this exception...